# Virtual machines cannot access each other

Tags: hyper-v

I have 2 Hyper-V VMs on the same host - one is XP and the other Windows 8.1.

They both have a virtual network adapter with the same VLAN ID value.

The firewall is switched off on both VMs.

I can ping the XP VM from the Win8.1 VM, but I can't ping the Win8.1 VM from the XP VM.

What else do I need to check?
[image]

Traceroute from XP as follows:
[image]

Comment: Why does your Windows XP VM have two virtual NICs that appear to be on the same subnet?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't know - is that bad?

Comment: It's the most likely cause of the problem, so yes, you should look into why that is, and most likely fix it.

Comment: I've deleted the second NIC and now it works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP VM has another adapter from the same subnet.

Try to remove it or change the subnet there.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem, as solved by @MichaelHampton.